# Debugging number of possible sums - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging, set, subset

I'm writing an algorithm that finds the number of possible sums from an array that contains unique values, and a second array that contains the quantity of each corresponding value in the first array. For example, the pair `[10, 20, 50] and [1, 2, 1]` indicates that the total number of elements that I am combining is actually `[10, 20, 20, 50]`, because there are two instances of the number 20.

My algorithm is currently passing every test except one, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why, since it is passing other, more complicated pairings.  Here is my algorithm so far:

```
function possibleSums(values, quantity) {
  const sums = new Set([]);

    //my recursive function that finds all possible combinations moving 
    //down from a specific starting index in the valueArrray:

  const combinations = (valueArray, countArray, position, currentSum) => {
    if (currentSum > 0) sums.add(currentSum);

    for(let i = position; i < valueArray.length; i++){
        if (countArray[i] === 0){
            continue;
        }
        currentSum += valueArray[i];
            //reduce the count of that value that is still available
        countArray[i]--;
            //send off a recursive call to find the sum with the next 
            //available value
        combinations(valueArray, countArray, i, currentSum);
            //return the original count since `i` is increasing past 
            //the current value's location in the valueArray
        countArray[i]++;
     }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        //start the recursive function calls at each index in the value array
    combinations(values, quantity, i, 0)
  }
  return sums.size
}
```

This algorithm passes array pairs like :

`[3, 1, 1] and [111, 84, 104]` with the expected output of 521

`[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] and [9, 19, 18, 12, 19]` with the expected output of 77

`[1, 2, 3] and [2, 3, 10000]` with the expected output of 30008

but is failing
`[10, 50, 100, 500] and [5, 3, 2, 2]` , outputting 96 when the expected output is 122

Can anyone spot what I am missing in my logic?

Comment: What type of debugging have you already attempted?

Comment: I'm confused by how the input yields the output. For example, `[3,1,1] and [111,84,104]`. If you do 3*111 + 1*84 + 1*104 you get 521 which is what you say you expect. However, `[5,3,2,2] and [10, 50, 100, 500]` you say should be 122?

Comment: Can you provide more test cases?

Comment: @mhodges The first array is values... like denominations of money, and the second array is the quantity of each value, so with the pair `[3,1,1] and [111,84,104]` there are 111 of the value 3, 84 of 1, and another 104 of 1... in the test case that I cannot pass `[10,50,100,500]` and `[5,3,2,2]`, there are 5 values of 10, 3 values of 50, and so on.  There are repeats of sums within the possible subSets (i.e. `[10,10,10,10,10]` = 50, `[50]` = 50, etc.), so I only want to return the total number of unique sums from all the possible subSets, not just the number of permutations.

Comment: @Veehmot more test cases are `[10, 50, 100] and [1, 2, 1]` which correctly returns 9, `[1, 2, 3] and [2, 3, 10000]` which correctly returns 30008, and `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] and [9, 19, 18, 12, 19]`, which correctly returns 77.

Comment: @PM77-1 I was using console.log as I was building the algorithm on smaller test cases.  I manually walked through what my code is doing, but this test case is too large for me to log and see what is happening.  And I can't identify what is different about this test case as opposed to the others so that I can write code to accommodate for it.  Perhaps that is a better question to ask... what about this test case is different from the others so that I can write that code.

Comment: Are you aware that you can set-up break points and inspect the actual values along the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

122 expected output is not too big a test case for logging :)

Let's log the parameters:

```js
...
const combinations = (valueArray, countArray, position, currentSum) => {
  console.log(countArray, position, currentSum)

  if (currentSum...
```

We see this, which makes sense:

```
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] 3 1400
```

But then we also see:

```
[ 0, 0, 1, 0 ] 3 1400
[ 0, 1, 0, 0 ] 3 1400
...
[ 1, 1, 1, 0 ] 3 1400
```

which don't.

Changing the current argument during the iteration seems to be affecting the variable during other calls.

Changing

```js
currentSum += valueArray[i];
...
combinations(valueArray, countArray, i, currentSum);
```

to

```js
//currentSum += valueArray[i];
...
combinations(valueArray, countArray, i, currentSum + valueArray[i]);
```

seems to do the trick.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you so much.  I'm working on a MacBook Air, and its tiny screen makes larger console logs overwhelming, so I try to keep them small.  Such a simple oversight, but it makes perfect sense to protect the value of currentSum.  This is a great concept to keep in mind when programming in the future.